# Vertically align nodes in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, graphs

I have taken to drawing automata in TikZ, as it will position the nodes for me, and generally requires very little post-processing in terms of options.

I know I can force nodes to be in the same horizontal layer by using the `[same layer]` directive.

[image]

How can I do this vertically (i.e. align 1,3,5 and 2,4)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,positioning,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{layered,trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{graph}[layered layout]
                    {1->2->3->4,
                    2->4,1->4,
                    1->3,4->5,2->5,
                    {[same layer]1,2},
                    {[same layer]3,4}
                    };
                    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not any more. TikZ v3.00 is officialy out on CTAN.

Comment: If you want layers being vertical, use `[grow left]` or `[grow right]`. There is also `[branch up]` (or down/left/right) and `[grid placement]`. See more on TikZ manual *§19.9.2 Placement on a Grid*. Or, after all, why not consider `tikz-cd`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{graph}[grid placement,wrap after=2]{
        1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5};
    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### More Details

You can

- assign a shift to a node.
- use `/` to declare a hole. In fact, `nema/txet` declars a node named nema but shown as txet.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{graph}[grid placement,wrap after=4]{
        /, 2             , 3              , /,
        5, 6[at={(.5,0)}], 7[at={(0,-.5)}], 8,
        9,10[at={(0,.5)}],11[at={(-.5,0)}],12,
        /,14             ,15};
    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Even More Details

Roughly speaking, a TikZ-node consists of two part: its shape and its shown text. The text-part is usually shown, and the shape-part is drawn when you say `[draw]`. A simple way to stop it is to say `[white]`, which makes the shape-part drawn in white. Or even stronger, say `[opacity=0]` in case your background is not white.

As to spread out nodes, you may adjust build-in parameters such as `[branch down=2cm,grow right=2cm]`.

Comment: Two questions (just cause I don't know much about the grid placement style).

1) is there a way to put nodes between grid points (say above the midpoint of 1 and

2) how does one insert a placeholder node (invis) for spacing?

Comment: Is there a way to get the node given by / to not be drawn at all (if I use nodes=[draw,circle]) I get an empty circle

Comment: Also, how can I make there be more space between nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following hack: use `same layer` to align horizontally, but also `rotate=90` the whole graph, so that horizontal becomes vertical (this does not rotate the node contents, which is perfect for this case):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,positioning,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{layered,trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,rotate=90]
    \begin{graph}[layered layout]
                    {1->2->3->4,
                    2->4,1->4,
                    1->3,4->5,2->5,
                    {[same layer]1,3,5},
                    {[same layer]2,4}
                    };
                    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: The issue is that then I still can only use [same layer] for one direction.